# 404 when enabling admin with Django

Tags: python, django, django-admin

I had correctly configured a Django app and had it running smoothly. However, when I went to enable the administration panel, I encountered a 404 error upon uncommenting this line:

`url(r'^admin/', include(admin.site.urls))`

Upon trying to access my site, I received this:

```
Using the URLconf defined in cms.urls, Django tried these URL patterns, in this order:

    1. ^admin/

The current URL, , didn't match any of these.
```

I can't figure out how to get around this error. Does anyone with some Django experience have a solution? Thanks!

EDIT: Here is the entire `urls.py` file:

```
from django.conf.urls.defaults import patterns, include, url

# Uncomment the next two lines to enable the admin:
from django.contrib import admin
admin.autodiscover()

urlpatterns = patterns('',
    # Examples:
    # url(r'^$', 'cms.views.home', name='home'),
    # url(r'^cms/', include('cms.foo.urls')),

    # Uncomment the admin/doc line below to enable admin documentation:
    # url(r'^admin/doc/', include('django.contrib.admindocs.urls')),

    # Uncomment the next line to enable the admin:
    url(r'^admin/', include(admin.site.urls)),
)
```

Comment: Seems that at current point, you are about to matching `''`, what's your whole urls files look like? Which url did you access, `yourdomain`, `yourdomain/` or `yourdomain/admin`?

Comment: Hi okm, I posted the entire urls.py in an edit. When I go to mydomain.com I get the error, however when I go to mydomain.com/admin, I get a 500 Internal Server Error

Comment: Check you have `'django.contrib.admin'` listed in `INSTALLED_APPS` in `settings.py`

Comment: which version of django are you using?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4292382/django-when-trying-domain-com-admin-gives-404-with-an-old-unexisting-urls-file

Comment: @JonClements It's listed & enabled.

Comment: @StefanNch It is Django 1.3.1

Comment: You get the 404 at `/` because you have no urlpattern defined to handle that. At `/admin/` you get a 500, so *that's* your problem. Post the traceback for that 500 error. Why are you asking about a 404?

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried, `http://yourdomain:port/admin` ? If you are using the default url, I would try
`http://127.0.0.1:8000/admin`