# 404 page when I visit the admin page

Tags: python, django, python-2.7, django-admin, django-1.5

I am working on my first Django website and am having a problem. Whenever I attempt to go on the admin page www.example.com/admin I encounter a 404 page. When I attempt to go on the admin site on my computer using `python manage.py runserver` it works. What info do you guys need to help me to fix my problem?

`url.py`

```
from django.conf.urls import patterns, include, url`
from django.contrib.staticfiles.urls import staticfiles_urlpatterns
from django.contrib import admin
from django.http import HttpResponseRedirect
admin.autodiscover()

urlpatterns = patterns('',
    url(r'^admin/', include(admin.site.urls)),
    url(r'^admin/doc/', include('django.contrib.admindocs.urls')),
    ....
```

```

Comment: Duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4292382/django-when-trying-domain-com-admin-gives-404-with-an-old-unexisting-urls-file

Comment: do any other urls work on the deployed site?

Comment: Yes, all other urls work.

Answer (score 0):

You must include the Django admin in your `INSTALLED_APPS` in the settings file (it's probably already there, but commented out).

You will also need to configure the URLs for the admin site, which should be in your site-wide urls.py, again, probably commented out but there.

If you have already done both of these things, please share your urls.py from the project itself.

Comment: I added it to the main question

Comment: And the admin app is enabled in your settings.py and you have restarted the runserver?

Comment: Yes, the server has been restarted.

Answer (score -1):

`python manage.py runserver` enables your application to run locally. You need to deploy your application using WSGI and Apache to access your page from other remove machines.

Refer to the configuration details https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.2/howto/deployment/modwsgi/

Comment: Asker mentioned he or she is able to access other URLs on his or her project without issue, it is limited to Django admin that is un-reachable. Hence, this issue is not related to the developer runserver. Additionally, your answer is incorrect in that runserver is not limited to local access, it only defaults to a local address, and so long as you provide it a public address, it is reachable remotely.